# Android: Facebook SDK Tutorial Step 3c friend list not appearing

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I am completing the facebook android sdk tutorial at:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/scrumptious/show-friends
everything was working great until i got to Step3c.  it runs but when i click the button and it brings up a view the view is blank without a friendlist.  anyone know what is causing this?
thanks
edward

my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.my2ndandroidapp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity 
        android:name=".PickerActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        ></activity>
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/app_id"/>
    <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity">     
</activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

my base list element class:

```
public abstract class BaseListElement {

private Drawable icon;
private String text1;
private String text2;
private int requestCode;
private BaseAdapter adapter;


protected abstract View.OnClickListener getOnClickListener();

public void setAdapter(BaseAdapter adapter) {
    this.adapter = adapter;
}

public BaseListElement(Drawable icon, String text1, String text2, int requestCode){
    super();
    this.icon = icon;
    this.text1 = text1;
    this.text2 = text2;
    this.requestCode = requestCode;
}

public int getRequestCode() {
    return requestCode;
}
public String getText1() {
    return text1;
}
public void setText1(String text1) {
    this.text1 = text1;
    if(adapter != null){
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
public String getText2() {
    return text2;
}
public void setText2(String text2) {
    this.text2 = text2;
    if(adapter != null){
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
public Drawable getIcon() {
    return icon;
}



}
```

my picker activity:

```
package com.example.my2ndandroidapp;

import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.widget.FriendPickerFragment;
import com.facebook.widget.PickerFragment;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;

public class PickerActivity extends FragmentActivity {

public static final Uri FRIEND_PICKER = Uri.parse("picker://friend");

private FriendPickerFragment friendPickerFragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.pickers);

    Bundle args = getIntent().getExtras();
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragmentToShow = null;
    Uri intentUri = getIntent().getData();

    if(FRIEND_PICKER.equals(intentUri)){
        if(savedInstanceState == null){
            friendPickerFragment = new FriendPickerFragment(args);
        }else{
            friendPickerFragment = 
                    (FriendPickerFragment)manager.findFragmentById(R.id.picker_fragment);
        }
        // set the listener to handle errors
        friendPickerFragment.setOnErrorListener(new PickerFragment.OnErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onError(PickerFragment<?> fragment,
                    FacebookException error) {

                PickerActivity.this.onError(error);

            }
        });
        // set the listener to handle button clicks
        friendPickerFragment.setOnDoneButtonClickedListener(
                new PickerFragment.OnDoneButtonClickedListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onDoneButtonClicked(
                            PickerFragment<?> fragment) {

                finishActivity();

            }   
        });
        fragmentToShow = friendPickerFragment;

    }else{
        // nothing to do, finish
        setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
        finish();
        return;
    }

    manager.beginTransaction()
           .replace(R.id.picker_fragment, fragmentToShow)
           .commit();
}

private void onError(Exception error){
    onError(error.getLocalizedMessage(), false);
}

private void onError(String error, final boolean finishActivity){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle(R.string.error_dialog_title)
           .setMessage(error)
           .setPositiveButton(R.string.error_dialog_button_text, 
                   new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                        if(finishActivity){
                            finishActivity();
                        }
                    }
                });
        builder.show();
}

private void finishActivity(){
    setResult(RESULT_OK, null);
    finish();
}


protected void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    if(FRIEND_PICKER.equals(getIntent().getData())){
        try{
            friendPickerFragment.loadData(false);
        }catch(Exception ex){
            onError(ex);
        }
    }
}

}
```

my selection fragment:

```
public class SelectionFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String TAG = "SelectionFragment";
private ProfilePictureView profilePictureView;
private TextView userNameView;
private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
private ListView listView;
private List<BaseListElement> listElements;


private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {

    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {

        onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);

    }
};
private static final int REAUTH_ACTIVITY_CODE = 100;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), callback);
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)   
{
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.selection, container, false);

    listView = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.selection_list);

    // set up the list view items, based on list of 
    // BaseListElement items

    listElements = new ArrayList<BaseListElement>();

    // add an item for the friend picker

    listElements.add(new PeopleListElement(0));

    // set the list view adapter

    listView.setAdapter(new ActionListAdapter(getActivity(), 
            R.id.selection_list, listElements));

    // find the user's profile picture custom view
    profilePictureView = (ProfilePictureView) view.findViewById(R.id.selection_profile_pic);
    profilePictureView.setCropped(true);

    // find the user's name view
    userNameView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.selection_user_name);

    // check for an open session
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if( session != null && session.isOpened() ){
        // get the user's data
        makeMeRequest(session);
    }

    //announceButton = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.announce_text);
    //messageButton = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.message_text);
    //listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.selection_list);
    //photoThumbnail = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.selected_image);

    //if (FacebookDialog.canPresentOpenGraphMessageDialog(activity)) {
    //    messageButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    //}

    //announceButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    //    @Override
    //    public void onClick(View view) {
    //        handleAnnounce(false);
    //    }
    //});
    //messageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    //    @Override
    //    public void onClick(View view) {
    //        handleAnnounce(true);
    //    }
    //});

    //init(savedInstanceState);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if( requestCode == REAUTH_ACTIVITY_CODE ){
        uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }else if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
        // do nothing for now
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    uiHelper.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    uiHelper.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    uiHelper.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

private void makeMeRequest(final Session session){

    // make an api call to get user data and define a
    // new callback to handle the response

    Request request = Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {

            // if the response is successful 
            if( session == Session.getActiveSession() ){
                if( user != null ){
                    // set the id for the ProfilePictureView
                    // view that in turn displays the profile picture.
                    profilePictureView.setProfileId(user.getId());
                    // set the TextView's text to the user's name.
                    userNameView.setText(user.getName());
                }
            }

            if( response.getError() != null ){

                // handle errors, will do so later.
            }

        }
    });
    request.executeAsync();
}

private void onSessionStateChange(final Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception)  
{

    if( session != null && session.isOpened() ){
        // get the user's data.
        makeMeRequest(session);
    }

}


private class ActionListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<BaseListElement>{

    private List<BaseListElement> listElements;

    public ActionListAdapter(Context context, int resourceId, List<BaseListElement> listElements) 
{

        super(context, resourceId, listElements);
        this.listElements = listElements;
        // set up as an observer for list item changes to 
        // refresh the view.

        for(int i = 0; i < listElements.size(); i++){
            listElements.get(i).setAdapter(this);
        }

    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

        View view = convertView;

        if(view == null){

            LayoutInflater inflater = 
                    (LayoutInflater)getActivity()
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, null);
        }

        BaseListElement listElement = listElements.get(position);
        if(listElement != null){
            view.setOnClickListener(listElement.getOnClickListener());
            ImageView icon = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            TextView text1 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text1);
            TextView text2 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text2);
            if(icon != null){
                icon.setImageDrawable(listElement.getIcon());
            }
            if(text1 != null){
                text1.setText(listElement.getText1());
            }
            if(text2 != null){
                text2.setText(listElement.getText2());
            }
        }

        return view;

    }

}


private class PeopleListElement extends BaseListElement {

    public PeopleListElement(int requestCode){

        super(getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.add_friends),
              getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.action_people),
              getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.action_people_default),
              requestCode);

    }

    protected View.OnClickListener getOnClickListener(){

        return new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                startPickerActivity(PickerActivity.FRIEND_PICKER, getRequestCode());

            }
        };
    }

}


private void startPickerActivity(Uri data, int requestCode){
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setData(data);
    intent.setClass(getActivity(), PickerActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
}
```

my main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private MainFragment mainFragment;
private static final String TAG = "MainFragment";
private static final int SPLASH = 0;
private static final int SELECTION = 1;
private static final int SETTINGS = 2;
private static final int FRAGMENT_COUNT = SETTINGS + 1;
private MenuItem settings;

private Fragment[] fragments = new Fragment[FRAGMENT_COUNT];

private boolean isResumed = false;
private boolean userSkippedLogin = false;

private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;

private Session.StatusCallback callback = 
        new Session.StatusCallback() {

            @Override
            public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {

                onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);

            }
        };

        @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
    //userSkippedLogin = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(USER_SKIPPED_LOGIN_KEY);
    }
    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, callback);
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    SplashFragment splashFragment = (SplashFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.splashFragment);
    fragments[SPLASH] = splashFragment;
    fragments[SELECTION] = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.selectionFragment);
    fragments[SETTINGS] = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.userSettingsFragment);

    FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
    for(int i = 0; i < fragments.length; i++) {
        transaction.hide(fragments[i]);
    }
    transaction.commit();

    splashFragment.setSkipLoginCallback(new SplashFragment.SkipLoginCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onSkipLoginPressed() {
                    userSkippedLogin = true;
                    showFragment(SELECTION, false);
                }
            });
}       

private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception){

    // only make changes if the activity is visible
    if(isResumed){
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        // get the number of entries in the back stack
        int backStackSize = manager.getBackStackEntryCount();
        // Clear the back stack
        for(int i = 0; i < backStackSize; i++){
            manager.popBackStack();
        }
        if(state.isOpened()){
            // if the session state is open:
            // show the authenticated fragment
            showFragment(SELECTION, false);
        }else if(state.isClosed()){
            // if the session state is closed:
            // show the login fragment
            showFragment(SPLASH, false);
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResumeFragments() {
    super.onResumeFragments();
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

    if(session != null && session.isOpened()){
        // if the session is already open,
        // try to show the selection fragment
        showFragment(SELECTION, false);
    }else{
        // otherwise present the splash screen
        // and ask the person to login.
        showFragment(SPLASH, false);
    }

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    uiHelper.onPause();
    isResumed = false;
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    uiHelper.onResume();
    isResumed = true;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if(item.equals(settings)){
        showFragment(SETTINGS, true);
        return true;
    }

    return false;

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // from previous tutorials
    Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);

}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    uiHelper.onDestroy();
}

private void showFragment(int fragmentIndex, boolean addToBackStack) {
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
    for (int i = 0; i < fragments.length; i++) {
        if (i == fragmentIndex) {
            transaction.show(fragments[i]);
        } else {
            transaction.hide(fragments[i]);
        }
    }
    if (addToBackStack) {
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    }
    transaction.commit();
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // only add the menu when the selection fragment is showing
    if(fragments[SELECTION].isVisible()){
        if(menu.size() == 0){
            settings = menu.add(R.string.settings);
        }
        return true;
    }else{
        menu.clear();
        settings = null;
    }
    return false;
}



}
```

my main fragment:

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String TAG = "MainFragment";
private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
private Button sendRequestButton;
private Button shareButton;

private static final List<String> PERMISSIONS = Arrays.asList("publish_actions");
private static final String PENDING_PUBLISH_KEY = "pendingPublishReauthorization";
private boolean pendingPublishReauthorization = false;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), callback);
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), null);
    //uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false);

    //LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.authButton);
    //authButton.setFragment(this);

    //shareButton = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.shareButton);
    //shareButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    //  
    //  @Override
    //  public void onClick(View v) {
    //      publishStory();
    //      
    //  }
    //});

    //sendRequestButton = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.sendRequestButton);
    //sendRequestButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    //  @Override
    //  public void onClick(View v) {
    //      sendRequestDialog();
    //  }
    //});

    if(savedInstanceState != null){
        pendingPublishReauthorization = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(PENDING_PUBLISH_KEY,  
false);
    }

    return view;
}

private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {

    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {

        onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);

    }
};

private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception){

    if(state.isOpened()){
        sendRequestButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        shareButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if(pendingPublishReauthorization && state.equals(SessionState.OPENED_TOKEN_UPDATED)){
            pendingPublishReauthorization = false;
            publishStory();
        }
    }else if(state.isClosed()){
        sendRequestButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        shareButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    //uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data, new FacebookDialog.Callback() {

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookDialog.PendingCall pendingCall, Exception error, Bundle data)  
{

            Log.e("Activity", String.format("Error: %s", error.toString()));

        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(FacebookDialog.PendingCall pendingCall, Bundle data) {

            Log.i("Activity", "Success!");

        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    uiHelper.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    uiHelper.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // for scenarios where the main activity is launched and user
    // session is not null, the session state change notification
    // may not be triggered.  Triggered it if it's open/closed.
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if(session != null && (session.isOpened() || session.isClosed())){
        onSessionStateChange(session, session.getState(), null);
    }
    uiHelper.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putBoolean(PENDING_PUBLISH_KEY, pendingPublishReauthorization);
    uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

private void sendRequestDialog(){

    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("message", "Learn how to make your Android apps social");

    WebDialog requestsDialog = (

            new WebDialog.RequestsDialogBuilder(getActivity(), 
                Session.getActiveSession(),
                params))
                .setOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener(){

                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(Bundle values,
                                FacebookException error) {

                            if(error != null){
                                if(error instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException){
                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                                            "Request cancelled",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }else{
                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                                            "Network Error",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            }else{
                                final String requestId = values.getString("request");
                                if(requestId != null){
                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                                            "Request sent",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }else{
                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                                            "Request cancelled",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            }

                        }
            })
            .build();
            requestsDialog.show();
}

private void publishStory(){
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

    if(session != null){

        // check for publish permissions
        List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();
        if(!isSubsetOf(PERMISSIONS, permissions)){
            pendingPublishReauthorization = true;
            Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new 
Session.NewPermissionsRequest(this, PERMISSIONS);
        session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
        return;
        }

        Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
        postParams.putString("name", "Facebook SDK for Android");
        postParams.putString("caption", "Build great social apps and get more installs");
        postParams.putString("description", "The Facebook SDK for Android makes it easier and  
faster to develop Facebook integrated Android apps.");
        postParams.putString("link", "https://developers.facebook.com/android");
        postParams.putString("picture", "https://raw.github.com/fbsamples/ios-3.x-
howtos/master/Images/iossdk_logo.png");

        Request.Callback callback = new Request.Callback() {

            @Override
            public void onCompleted(Response response) {

                JSONObject graphResponse = response.getGraphObject().getInnerJSONObject();
                String postId = null;
                try{
                    postId = graphResponse.getString("id");
                }catch(JSONException e){
                    Log.i(TAG, "JSON error " + e.getMessage());
                }

                FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
                if(error != null){
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),  
error.getErrorMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), postId,   
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        };

        Request request = new Request(session, "me/feed", postParams, HttpMethod.POST, callback);

        RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
        task.execute();
    }
}

private boolean isSubsetOf(Collection<String> subset, Collection<String> superset){
    for(String string : subset){
        if(!superset.contains(string)){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add FriendPickerFragment

```
friendPickerFragment.setFriendPickerType(FriendPickerFragment.FriendPickerType.TAGGABLE_FRIENDS);
```